# Native lazy load image reflow (loading='"lazy")

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, lazy-loading

When attempting to use the new `loading="lazy"` attribute on an `img` tag i get the following error:

`[Intervention] An <img> element was lazyloaded with loading=lazy, but had no dimensions specified. Specifying dimensions improves performance. See https://crbug.com/954323`

When looking online, i came across the follow link specifies that adding `width` 
 and `height` attributes to the `img` helps the browser avoid reflow by painting a placeholder to the screen:

https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading#image-loading

My question is, it's pretty uncommon these days to hard code a `width` and `height` of an image, if i override these in my style sheet with something like the following, will i still benefit from avoiding reflow?

```
img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Thanks in advance
Sami.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is no... Even if 'reflow' behaviour is strictly dependent on the browser's implementation, it's pretty valid to assume that almost any modification of the DOM will lead to a 'reflow', especially if it involves changing dimensions (elements displacing other elements) or adding/removing a node. It would be still advisable to add height and width attributes that will not only suppress the error/warning, but will also work as a fallback.

Most importantly, you will avoid an ugly 'jump' effect when the image loads if the written height/width matches the final style.

Additional note: 'reflows' are to be avoided when possible, but in your case, image loading will happen only once, so I would say It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

As Ernesto Stifano mentions, there is no way to get around the reflow issue without specifying the ratio of the image (i.e. letting the browser know a width *and* height attribute for the image).

If you don't want to specify an exact width and height though, you can add an `intrinsicsize` attribute instead (see [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/intrinsic-size/)) but you still need to set a width and height property (using the interface `intrinsicsize="300 x 400"`, for example).

This can allow you to be able to set `width: 100%` in the CSS and not have to worry about setting `height: auto` constantly, which may help.

Answer (score 0):

additionally to what Ernesto Stifano has mentioned previously, the current development regarding "intrinsicsize" is more or less to "Compute img/video/canvas aspect ratio from width and height HTML attributes" - compare to https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/pull/18945 and https://github.com/WICG/intrinsicsize-attribute/issues/16